# In Powershell, do I need to use Stop-Process AND CloseMainWindow()?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to this **Powershell** lark, and I understood that `Stop-Process` should be sufficient to end a task. However, it didn't close the newly created window and it left me uncertain if the process had stopped or not.

But, after doing some ID checking, I discovered that the process ID had been removed from the list. Is it, therefore, best practice to call `Stop-Process` and then `CloseMainWindow()` ... or is `CloseMainWindow()` sufficient on its own?

```
Cls
$notepadId = Start-Process notepad -passthru
Echo "" "notepadId = "
Echo $notepadId.Id

Echo "" "Current Notepad tasks:"
Get-Process notepad
Start-Sleep -s 2

Echo "" "Stopping Task:"
Stop-Process $notepadId.Id -Force

Echo "" "Closing Window:"
(Get-Process -Id $notepadId.Id).CloseMainWindow()

Start-Sleep -s 2
Echo "" "Tasks remaining:"
Get-Process notepad
Pause
```

Comment: Add -force parameter to make sure process is stopped. That will be enough.

Comment: Stopping the process (without -Force) seems to close the window for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's not working for you, but here's how I'd write it:

```
Cls
$notepadProcess = Start-Process notepad -passthru
Start-Sleep -s 2
Stop-Process $notepadProcess
```

The return-value from Start-Process is actually a Process object, not just the ID.  If you pass that process object to Stop-Process, it knows what to do.  However, a few experiments suggest that Stop-Process is *not* synchronous, so if you do this:

```
Cls
$notepadProcess = Start-Process notepad -passthru
Start-Sleep -s 2
Stop-Process $notepadProcess
get-process Notepad -ErrorAction Ignore
```

You will probably still see the process listed, however a few hundred milliseconds sleep before the Get-Process command should be sufficent to eliminate it.